# Engineering Stack Exchange tag & Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

There is a whole question section on the Engineering Stack Exchange about electrical engineering, but there is already an [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com).

Is there a difference between the Engineering's tag ["electrical engineering"](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical-engineering) and the Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange? From a quick overview on Engineering Stack Exchange, it seems that some questions are about electrical norm and design which is the purpose of the Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The engineering site will probably better answer electrical questions that require professional engineering certifications (ie, a state or government issued professional engineer certification.)

Both sites will be able to answer such questions, and the reality is that some will even find a home on diy as a homeowner type question.

As such there's a lot of overlap, but the main difference is the audience. Do you want your question answered by an electronics engineer - go to electrical.  Do you want it answered by a professional engineer - go to engineering.

There's no guarantee you'll get the audience you want, but you have a better chance at the appropriate site.